# Channel distortion/noise simulation on recorded audio files

Tags: audio, voip, telephony, noise, noise-reduction

I want to simulate channel distortion/noise such as telephony, VOIP and etc. on some previously recorded audio files. Can someone guide me by recommending some tools in this area?

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but be sure to [provide enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: Try the StackExchange Sound Design community, you should get plenty of help there.